# Android custom keyboardview allways visible (Ignore back button)

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm using a custom keyboard with keyboardview.
The keyboard is in the xml of the activity, as you can see here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittextOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#3498db"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:background="#9b59b6" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When the user uses the back button on the device keyboard disappears, as is normal.

My question is: How can I make impossible to hide the keyboard? 
My intention is ALWAYS visible.

I tried android: `windowSoftInputMode = "stateAlwaysVisible"` but does not work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your keyboard class. The onWindowHidden method get called if you press back button or the keyboard disappear for other reasons.

```
@Override
public void onWindowHidden()
{

    //Nothing
    super.onWindowHidden();
}
```